# Converting Client input char to int

Tags: temperature-sensor, tcpip, convert

I'm trying to print out the temperature from a DS18B20 sensor to my app via a tpc connection. Because I have two sensors connected I will need to call the one needed by an Index. This index comes from my app and is a char value which I need to convert it to an int for comparision later. The problem I have is the conversion from to input char value to int. 
My code:

```cpp
void loop() {
  //setting default sensor to 0
  sensorindex = 0;
  //starting server
  WiFiClient client = wifiServer.available();

  if (client) {
  Serial.write("Client connected");
          client.println("connected");
    while (client.connected()) {
      while (client.available()>0) {

        //instream from client/mobile device
        char c = client.read();
        //converting char c to int
        sensorindex = String(c).toInt() ;  
        Serial.println(sensorindex);
      }

      //comparing client input to DS18B20 sensor index
      sensors.requestTemperatures();
      if(sensorindex == 1){
           client.println(sensors.getTempCByIndex(1));
           Serial.println("Index 1");
      }
      if(sensorindex == 0){
           client.println(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
             Serial.println("Index 0");
      }

      delay(50);
    }

    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  }
}
```

The serial output:

```cpp
Client connectedIndex 0
Index 0
Index 0
Index 0
Index 0
Index 0
1
0
Index 0
Index 0
Index 0
Index 0
Index 0
Index 0
Index 0
Index 0
Client disconnected
```

When I type in 1 from my android app it shows

```cpp
1
0
```

in the output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you present a sketch with WiFi if you ask about Serial input conversion?

Comment: @Juraj It's the same in the end because I'm I will get a char value in both cases which I need to convert to an integer. And I've never asked directly for a serial input conversion but rather the wifi input, which is basically the same

Comment: so while client is connected you print the output based on the last sensorindex value. why?

Comment: So it refreshed the app every 50ms to show the current temp of the sensor which is chosen by the index value, which is based on the input which came from the app

Comment: so the only thing that bothers you is the 0 after the 1?

Comment: Yep because it should only return one line with the given integer but instead prints out two lines. And I can't use this integer or whatever it is to compare it because it this int hasn't got the exact value which came from the app, there must be a way to smoothly convert a char to int. Or at least a digit of a char.

Comment: do you send it as println? then the '\n' would be the second char

Comment: Oh yeah makes sense but why does it convert a 1 into a 10 in the first place?

Comment: `1` is 1 and `\n` doesn't convert at all so toInt returns 0. you convert single chars - digits of the sent number (what could be done as `c - 48`).

Comment: @Juraj When I use sensorindex = c-48; it just prints out 1-38 or 0-38. How can I get rid of the second char digit? I tried using atoi but that just gave me an error cuz it isnt a const char

Comment: all c < 32 are nonprintable. but if you want to read the number, not only the digits, then use `client.parseInt()`

Comment: Tried client.parseInt() but it just printed out the digit I want, then waits and prints out a zero. Looks like a timeout which retuns a 0 if no other digit is transmitted.